# Настройка htaccess для MVC

Tags: .htaccess

Уже вторую неделю ломаю голову и понять не могу, как сделать так чтобы домены склеивались и все остальное проходило через точку входа index.php, привожу пример:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=permanent]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/{2,}(.*)$
RewriteRule (.*) %1/%2 [R=301,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

При такой склейке, с www на no-www MVC начинает вообще зависать на столько что на сайт не зайдешь? Что делать-то!
Good or Guru dev/Plis help

Comment: В браузере откройте инструменты разработчика на вкладке "сеть" и посмотрите на возможные редиректы. По `.htaccess`: перенесите блок с обработкой слэшей выше блока с перенаправлением на `index.php`, а у `index.php` поставьте флаг `L`

Comment: Не работает, делал как сказали, а вот на счет консоли еще пока не совсем умею пользоваться, применял только для JS

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule "^(.*)//+(.*)$" "$1/$2" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond "%{HTTP_HOST}" "^www\.(.+)$" [NC]
RewriteRule "^" "http://%1%{REQUEST_URI}" [L,R=permanent]

RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" !-f
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_FILENAME}" !-d
RewriteRule "^" "index.php" [L]
# index.php в папке с htaccess
```

отслеживать в логе с `LogLevel rewrite:trace8`

Comment: Про бывал как вы сказали, но почему то стирает .ru, и хождение по категория не возможно при таком раскладе правил. Можете написать правило которое будет обрабатывать все не через слеши а начиная с www и пусть все отправляет на без www, это вообще возможно? и да если урл у меня ЧПУ то знаки вопросов и многие другие символы под шаблон не подходят.

Comment: @JJXX редиректы permanent/301 кэшируются браузером, поэтому на время тестов лучше хотя бы R=303, и после очистки кэша и перезапуска браузера проверяйте. А то браузер может отдавать кэшированные редиректы после ошибочных правок.